# How to access the original value of a record in a with expression

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Given a record

```
public record Address(string Name);
```

How can I access the original value of a property in a `with` expression? What I would like to do is something like:

```
var address = new Address("foo");
var extendedAddress = address with { Name = $"{Name} - bar" }; // does not compile
```

so that `extendedAddress == "foo - bar"`.

Is there a way of referencing the original record that is being overridden so that the values can be "extended"?

TO BE MORE SPECIFIC

The example I gave is misleading since one could simply do:

```
var extendedAddress = address with { Name = $"{address.Name} - bar" };
```

But what I'm looking for is to achieve this within a single expression. Something like:

```
customers.Select(x => x.GetAddress() with Name = $"{Name} - bar")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing automatic here, for good reason: `Name` already has resolution rules (an instance member `this.Name`, a static `Name`, a type called `Name`, etc). Just use `address.Name` from a local, perhaps via a `let` expression in LINQ

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid so. I guess, in most cases there will always be decent work-arounds. For my second example, one could simply chain the selects: `...Select(x => x.GetAddress()).Select(a => a with $"{a.Name} - bar")`. Thanks Marc.

Comment: Or just `.Select(x => { var a = x.GetAddress(); return address with { $"{a.Name} - Bar" } })` --  no need to introduce extra object allocations and cost